# How to avoid Runnable callback leak?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, reference, weak-references

I have codes below that will execute a callback from another thread when I finish the activity. So how to **avoid** to call the callback or the codes in the callback **when the activity has been finished**?

```
public static interface Callback{
    public void onCallback();
}

class ActivityA {
    TextView tv = ...;
    Handler handler = ...;
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Business.callThread(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCallback() {
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        tv.setText("xxxx");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

class Business {
    public static void callThread(final Callback listener) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000); //sleep 5s;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                listener.onCallback();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collector counts references to objects. However, there are couple of reference types. Useful in your case is [`WeakReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html):

> Weak reference objects, which do not prevent their referents from being made finalizable, finalized, and then reclaimed.

Create runnable as a class with constructor:

```
static class CallbackRunnable implements Runnable {
    WeakReference<Callback> listener;

    public CallbackRunnable(Callback listener) {
        this.listener = new WeakReference<Callback>(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000); //sleep 5s;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (listener.get() == null) {
            return;
        }
        listener.get().onCallback();
    }
}
```

then call listener like:

```
if (listener.get() == null) {
    return;
}
listener.get().onCallback();
```

`callThread` method implementation:

```
public static void callThread(final Callback listener) {
    new Thread(new CallbackRunnable(listener)).start();
}
```

Comment: Well, I really do not very understand this, when `listener.get()==null` will be true? and why?

Comment: When Call is declared by `new Callback()` it holds reference to `Activity` (it is inner object declared inside `Activity`). When Activity is to be destroyed it is marked by Garbage collector. When Garbage collector needs memory, it removes previously marked objects. But it decides automatically when to be invoked and what to clear. That is a really simple and naive description, but it mainly works like that.

Comment: I catch you. But how do you know the `new Callback` holds the reference of  the activity?

Comment: [Here](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/finally-understanding-how-references-work-in-android-and-java-26a0d9c92f83) is the most recent interesting acrticle about Java references.

Comment: if call this `new WeakReference< Callback >(new Callback()) `, the `listener.get() == null` will always be true!

Comment: This won't work. `WeakReference` must be kept somewhere, not declared dynamically. Refactored the answer.

Comment: You mean it should be a activity's member var, yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131043/discussion-between-zhao-rocky-and-r-zagorski).